# View the most recent categories created in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a section on my site that will display the last five categories created. How could I do that?

The code below is what I want, just like to know how to apply in order, if the latest published categories.

```
<?php
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $categories=get_categories('child_of='.$cat);
    if ($categories) { 
?>

<div class="subcat-archive">
<?php
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $categories=get_categories('child_of='.$cat);
    if ($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $term) {
            echo $title . '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> | '; 
        }
    }
?>
</div>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `orderby` parameter to `'id'` and the `order` parameter to `'DESC'`. The IDs of WordPress objects are sequential so recent categories will have a higher ID than older categories. You can update your code like so:

```
$categories=get_categories(array(
    'child_of'=>$cat,
    'orderby'=>'id',
    'order'=>'DESC'
));
```

Check out the docs for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories.